SimpleDateFormat working on Non-English Locale(Nepali or Devnagari)
I am having confusion on understanding the following piece of code:

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String parsingDate = "२०२४-११-३० १२:५१:४६";
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(parsingDate);
            System.out.println("Date " + date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

The value stored in parsingDate "२०२४-११-३० १२:५१:४६" is Nepali language equivalent of "2024-11-30 12:51:46".
I assumed that the above piece of code would throw an exception, but to my surprise, the code works perfectly. The output of the program is Sat Nov 30 12:51:46 NPT 2024
How does it work?

Is your jvm's default locale set to Nepal? Or user.language is set to Nepali?

Note that since Java 8, you should use date-time API. When parsing dates, you can explicitly set the locale.

@Abra is right. Note also the correct format for ISO is "२०२४-११-३०T१२:५१:४६" for that Locale. Get that right and not only will your code be standards-compliant but you won't need formatting classes, as in LocalDateTime.parse("२०२४-११-३०T१२:५१:४६");

I suspect this works for any Locale and any Unicode digits - most probably it is using the numeric value of the unicode characters (e.g. Character.getNumericValue('२') == 2)

My system's language is not set to Nepali @NathanHughes

@g00se No, using LocalDateTime fails. See Ideone.com.

@BasilBourque perhaps that might reflect the lack of OS support for that locale?

@g00se (A) No, the ne_NP locale exists on Ideone.com. See similar code as above that also dumps known locales to console. (B) Nor does specifying the locale work with LocalDateTime:  LocalDateTime.parse (         "२०२४-११-३० १२:५१:४६" ,         DateTimeFormatter                 .ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )                 .withLocale ( Locale.of ( "ne" , "NP" ) ) )

Yes it's weird. What's even weirder is that I think I had it working at one point. Maybe I imagined it

( @g00se ) some points regarding the IDEone code above: 1) setting default Locale does not help, I suspect that the constants (ISO_*) used as default are created before the default is set - an exlicit created DateTimeFormatter must be used (e.g. DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.localizedBy( ne_NP)); 2) IDEone uses Java 12 and it apparently does not work with that, neither does it work with Java 17 (local test), it works with Java 21 and 24; ( 3) new Locale() constructors are deprecated ) ...

... background info: the DecimlaStyle of DateTimeFormatter is used to parse digits, actually DecimalStyle::getZeroDigit is subtracted from the characters to get the decimal value. For Example, on my system,
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.getDecimalStyle() is returning DecimalStyle[0+-.] even after changing the default Locale to ne_NP; DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.localizedBy(ne_NP).getDecimalStyle() results in DecimalStyle[०+-.] (note the slightly changed ०)

@user85421 Well done - you cracked the problem! DateTimeFormatter::localizedBy works, whereas ::withLocale doesn't: jshell> dtfNE.format(LocalDateTime.parse("२०२४-११-३०T१२:५१:४६", dtfNE)); $23 ==> "२०२४-११-३०T१२:५१:४६"

@user85421  In Java 23.0.1, this code LocalDateTime.parse ( "२०२४-११-३० १२:५१:४६" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale ( Locale.of ( "ne" , "NP" ) ) ) throws java.time.format.DateTimeParseException. What am I missing?

@Basil -- withLocale() != localizedBy() (also explained in previous comment) - to set the decimal style, localizedBy() should be used (as documented)

( and DecimalStyle.getZeroDigit() is used to convert digits to number [ just subtracted from the char { no code point <yet?> } ] )

The way I see it this is one of the thousands of problems with SimpleDateFormat. You don’t want to allow digits of just any local alphabet in your string. You know which digits you expect, and as the question hints, you want to be notified if there are other digits instead. Apparently you can’t have that. With the modern DateTimeFormatter you can specify which digits to expect, which is what we need (you could even specify different digits for the date and the time if needed, by combining two formatters into one).

Not an 'answer' as such but worthwhile to show the correct way of dealing with your non-ISO-compliant datetime strings, avoiding the use of obsolescent classes. Thanks to user85421 for the correct way to deal with localisation for the Devangari digits:
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NepalTimeParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfNepali = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(ISO_DATE).appendLiteral(" ")
                .append(ISO_TIME).toFormatter().localizedBy(Locale.of("ne", "NP"));
        String parsingDate = "२०२४-११-३० १२:५१:४६";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            parsingDate = args[0];
        }
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(parsingDate, dtfNepali);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}


I really do appreciate the effort you and @user85421 have put into this

If I got the question right, all answers so far (first one, second one) do not come close to the desired answer.
My understanding is, that the thread opener was surprised that the method SimpleDateFormat::parse is able to handle non-arabic digits.
Which number signs (characters for digits) are valid digits is not related to the current Locale selected – the TO confirmed that they did not use the Nepali Locale, one comment says that the result was the same for the German Locale. It is just a definition made by Unicode which character is a numerical character.
And obviously does the parse() of java.text.SimpleDateFormat translate each valid numerical character properly to its numerical value before it tries to parse the String as a date/time value. That's a nice feature to have …
That the methods and APIs dealing with java.util.Date are long time outdated is true, but completely unrelated to the question. Not to mention that the trick does not work with java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.

I think you got the question right. However it seems that the asker got wrong whether to use SimpleDateFormat  at all. It’s obsolescent, and it was a notorious trouble maker back when it was used. So maybe put bluntly, your answer is correct and irrelevant.

In simple terms, SimpleDateFormat knows a Locale, and unless you explicitly set it to something different, it will be your system's default Locale.  It uses that Locale when parsing or formatting dates, which is what you're seeing here.
Of course SimpleDateFormat has been obsolete for almost 12 years now, and you should be using the java.time equivalent class, which is DateTimeFormatter.  This class also knows a Locale, so it should act the same way (although I've never tried it in Nepal).

( almost 11 years - Java 8 was released March 2014... we are still in 2024 :- ) ) and, again, SimpleDateFormat does not use  the (default) Locale for parsing numbers (https://ideone.com/ezi3x5)
